# unusual affect after changing the system

Tags: android

I have been developing  in a system,but some hardware problem happened so had to change the system,now when I open the the app in eclipse in other system it gives error saying R.id.Filename in which filename cannot be resolved to a variable even though there are files resembling to it

Comment: Have you tried doing a clean and rebuild?

Comment: ya no success in that either

Comment: After doing the clean/rebuild, have you got the R.java file created (it should be in the gen folder)?

Comment: Delete the existing R.java and do Project --> Clean.             Double check if you've imported android.R unintentionally, if so, remove that and do Project --> Clean.